# what's best solution for interactive book on ipad device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I plan use HTML,

ebook designer( HTML page builder) -> embed in iPad -> user see the book (browse html, interact the page tap video/voice etc)

but not sure whether is best solution, consider extendability, I think that is feasible...

please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the two best interactive eBook frameworks for iOS are ...

1. [The Baker Framework](http://bakerframework.com/)
2. [The PugPig Framework](http://pugpig.com/)